# symfony and doctrine get 500 error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I developed the website in local server. Then I transferred files to web server. but when I tested the website, it reported 500 Internal Server Error. I checked the database parameters and config file. everything is good. Anyone has idea about this error?

the following code cause this problem:

```
$restarant = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("LeoFoodRadarBundle:Restaurant")->find($id);
```

I checked log and found the problem was that doctrine cannot connect to database:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mayifann_foodradar.timeTable' doesn't exist (uncaught exception) at /home/mayifann/domains/test/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 47 [] []
```

Actually, I have the table named timetable in database, and it runs very well in local server.
what's the reason cause this problem? Should I change the table name from timetable to timeTable?

Comment: What is the exact exception message returned from Symfony? Also, could it be you spelled restaurant wrong?

Comment: If Robert is not right please add some logs from symfony and/or your web server

Comment: when I changed the table name to timeTable, it works. But what cause this problem? why it works in the local server without changing the table name?

Comment: This might sounds like a case sensitivity problem ? Some MySQL configuration might be case sensitive or not. So Maybe your server and local host do not have the same configuration...